# Haskell - Creating a list by using functions

Tags: haskell

I want to do what the title says, but it keeps me showing errors. I put my code below.

```
data Tree a = Leaf a | Branch (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving Show

treeToList :: Tree a -> [a]
treeToList (Leaf x) = [x]
treeToList (Branch a b) = (treeToList a):(treeToList b)
```

It would show something like this:

treeToList Branch (Branch (Leaf 2) (Leaf 3)) (Leaf 4)

[2,3,4]

Comment: I see this kind of tree (with data in leaves but not in branches) every now and then, and always wonder what's the point of it.

Comment: @n.m. Isn't it recursively defined in Branch anyway ?

Comment: @Sibi Consider this: `data List a = Continue (List a) | Finish a`. Makes sense?

Comment: @n.m. But your data structure only allows to store one data. (eg: `Continue (Continue (Continue (Finish 3)))`) ?

Comment: @n.m.- my filesystem is a tree with data in the leaves (files) but not in the branches (the dirs)....  Makes sense to me.

Comment: @jamshidh does your filesystem have directories with no names, access rights, or modification dates?

Comment: @n.m. There are definitely cases where this is useful. Consider some Huffman coded data. You build a binary tree like this out of a frequency table and you read in some data. The data is made up of variable length "names". Each bit tells you to either go left or right in the tree and when you eventually reach a leaf node, you know that you've read in that entire encoded symbol and you start again for the next symbol. This is a very compact way to store certain kinds of data.

Comment: @n.m.- Well, yeah, if we consider all info as data, then even Jose's example has some data associated with it (his first or second position is pretty much the same as my filename....).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first pattern match you get a value of type list. Now all you have to do is concatenate them when you pattern match the `Branch` constructor.

```
treeToList :: Tree a -> [a]
treeToList (Leaf x) = [x]
treeToList (Branch a b) = (treeToList a) ++ (treeToList b)
```

Demo in ghci:

```
*Main> treeToList (Branch (Branch (Leaf 2) (Leaf 3)) (Leaf 4))
[2,3,4]
```